# Getting Error while opening files through vim

Tags: vimrc, line-breaks, unicode, encoding, cygwin

I am trying to use `unicode` characters in vim. Since `msdos` prompt didnt support unicode, I downloaded `cygwin`.

I added some commands in `.vimrc` through cygwin.
Basic commands like setting `encoding`, `fileencoding` to utf8. Since cygwin also doesn't support diacritits or multiple characters. So, to add Tamil character keymappings and abbreviations, I opened notepad.

When I opened the same file through `notepad`, I got multiple sentences in single line. The new line characters were hidden. when i move to the end of line, that cursor has to be moved twice. So, I manually entered a new line by pressing `Enter` everytime and saved it.
I thought that the fileformat might be wrong and gave `:set fileformat+=msdos,unix` in vimrc.

Then, I opened cygwin and inside it, opened a file through vim. I am getting an error like
`E492: Not an editor command : ^M` for every line in the vimrc file.
I understand that the newline character is causing trouble, but dont know how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: Changing ^M to \n, \r didnt work.

Comment: `fileformat` and `fileformats` are two different options. It doesn't make any sense to set `fileformat` (without an `s`) in your `.vimrc`, and it also doesn't make any sense to set it using `+=` as you do above. Furthermore, `msdos` is not a valid value for either option. I'd recommend a thorough read-through of all three of the following help sections: `:help file-formats`, `:help 'ff'` and `:help 'ffs'`.

Answer (score 1):

Though Cygwin is installed in Windows, it resembles linux.
So, setting the `fileformat` to unix solves the problem.

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

Now, the unicode characters are accepted by Cygwin.